# Text Vector to Decision Tree in RapidMiner

Tags: rapidminer

1 ad-jerry ad-bruckheimer ad-chase ad-premier ad-sept ad-th ad-clip ad-bruckheimer ad-chase page found

-1 ad-symptom ad-muscle ad-weakness ad-genetic ad-disease ad-symptom ad-include ad-search ad-learn page found

1 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1 6:1 7:1 8:1 9:1

-1 8:1 9:1 429:1 430:1 431:1 432:1 433:1 434:1 435:1 436:1

I've text vector & its corresponding term vector, I want to learn a Decision Tree using ID3 algorithm in rapid miner, But I don't know how to process such data for ID3 Algorithm. I've tried to run ID3(Read CSV->ID3->Model) over term vector but I don't know whether It's working correct or not. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The ID3 Alogrithm does not accept numerical attributes.  You will need to perform a preprocessing step or choose an alternative learning algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

To convert numerical to nominal, you need to use one of the Discretize operators. These create  bins into which the numerical values are placed. The attribute's name remains the same but its type changes to nominal. The value that an attribute has for a particular example is then dictated by the bin into which it was placed.